# FINDSTR - Stop on last string match

Tags: batch-file

I have a hundred text files where I am trying to extract lines containing the word foobar, but the text files also contain multiple sets of duplicates.

I have this, which obviously spits each line containing foobar, which works but produces the file with duplicates

```
findstr /C:"foobar" test.txt  > result.txt
```

For example

test.txt contains

```
foobar 

foobar 

foorbar            ##
```

Then this repeats further down the text file, how could I get it to just stop on "foobar ##" where ## represents an integer and delete everything thereafter?

I tried this, but the cmd window hangs, not sure on what.

```
@echo off


findstr /b /C:"foobar" test.txt  > results

SET STOPSTR="foobar              ##"
for /f %%a in (results) do (

FINDSTR /c:"foobar" > newresults
IF %%a==%STOPSTR% GOTO END

)
:END
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
for /f "delims=" %%a in (results) do (

 IF "%%a"=="%STOPSTR%" GOTO END
 echo %%a
)
)>newresults
```

Note that the extra pair of parentheses acts to redirect the `echo` output to the file.

If you want to retain the line containing your stopstring, reverse the `if` and `echo` lines.

The elements in the `if` need to be quoted since they (may) contain separators (like spaces)

The `"delims="` ensures that the entire line is assigned to `%%a` otherwise just the first space-delimited token will be assigned (see `for/?` from the prompt for docco)

Comment: Hmm. maybe I am missing something, what you provided me only outputs the STOPSTR line, but does not include everything before it. I assumed you saying to reverse the IF and ECHO would print each line (%%a) but it gives the same output. Even removing the IF line does not ECHO each line before the STOPSTR. My brain hurts.

Comment: Scratch that above, It actually still echos the entire results file, does not just stop on STOPSTR line.

Comment: Two problems: Since you have included the quotes in `stopstr`, the quotes should be *omitted* around `%stopstr%` in the `if` statement. I customarily `set` variables without quotes and insert them when the variable is used (if applicable). The other is that the number of spaces in the value assigned to your `stopstr` is different from the number of spaces on the data line you've provided. There's also a superfluous `r` in the data line.

Comment: I've been testing a simpler file, it seems that even though I hard code the stopstring, it does not match with %%a, not sure how to fix this.

Comment: If yo have `SET STOPSTR="foobar              ##"` and `IF "%%a"==%STOPSTR% GOTO END` then the `if` statement should take, *provided* the string assigned to `stopstr` is *exactly* the same as the string in `%%a`. Many factors can confound this. The first step would be to copy the stop-string from the file and paste it into the quotes in the `set` statement. Another would be to use `SET "STOPSTR=foobar              ##"` and `IF "%%a"=="%STOPSTR%" GOTO END` The `set` syntax here ensures no trailing spaces are included in the value assigned. The data file may have trailing spaces or TABs...

Comment: Thats it! Has to match the line perfectly, now to get it to work with wildcards. Thank you.