# For Loop through text file only outputs last line

Tags: batch-file

I think I am about to have an a brain aneurysm. I am trying to print the lines of a text file to a new file, but it only outputs the last line. I have done this a dozen times, now I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (results.txt) do (
   echo %%A
) > imsofrustrated.txt
PAUSE
```

Am I literally retarded? This is in reference to a previous question I posted. 
[FINDSTR - Stop on last string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717043/findstr-stop-on-last-string-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` is to redirect output and overwrite whatever is in the file.
`>>` is to redirect output and append to the file.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (results.txt) do (
   echo %%A
) >> imsofrustrated.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, you just confirmed I'm retarded. I thought I did try that.